# Apache's root directory in my provisions file

Tags: apache, directory, vagrant, root

I have a question. I finally found out how to change the root directory of apache. I simply have to edit this line of code `DocumentRoot /var/www/html` but since vagrant is amazing and has this provision script, I thought that I could tell apache the root directory from here.
Because think of it if i could use this provision script for every time I make a new website that would save me a lot of time. I wouldn't have to like go to the config file and change it every time

ADDED:

This is how my provision script looks now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PROJECT="foundation"
PROJECT_LOG="foundation"

MYSQL_PASSWORD="wachtwoord"

set -o nounset -o errexit -o pipefail -o errtrace

error() {
   local sourcefile=$1
   local lineno=$2
   echo "ERROR at ${sourcefile}:${lineno}; Last logs:"
   grep "${PROJECT}" /var/log/syslog | tail -n 20
}

trap 'error "${BASH_SOURCE}" "${LINENO}"' ERR

oe() { "$@" 2>&1 | logger -t "${PROJECT}" > /dev/null; }
ol() { echo "[${PROJECT_LOG}] $@"; }

export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

ol 'Updating repository caches'
oe sudo apt-get -q -y update

ol 'Adding apt repositories'
oe sudo apt-get -q -y install python-software-properties
oe sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6

ol 'Updating repository caches (second time)'
oe sudo apt-get -q -y update

ol "Installing misc packages"
oe sudo apt-get -q -y install language-pack-nl

ol 'Installing Apache 2'
oe sudo apt-get -q -y install apache2
oe sudo systemctl restart apache2
oe sudo systemctl status apache2

ol "Installing PHP"
oe sudo apt-get -q -y install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mysql php5-curl php5-gd php5-intl php-pear php5-imagick php5-imap php5-mcrypt php5-memcached php5-ming php5-ps php5-pspell php5-recode php5-snmp php5-sqlite php5-tidy php5-xmlrpc php5-xsl php5-xcache


debconf-set-selections <<< 'phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/dbconfig-install boolean true'
debconf-set-selections <<< 'phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/app-password-confirm password ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}'
debconf-set-selections <<< 'phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/mysql/admin-pass password ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}'
debconf-set-selections <<< 'phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/mysql/app-pass password ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}'
debconf-set-selections <<< 'phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/reconfigure-webserver multiselect apache2'

ol "Installing PHPmyadmin"
apt-get install -y phpmyadmin

# Make Composer available globally
ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf



ol 'Installing Sendmail'
oe sudo apt-get -q -y install sendmail

ol 'Restarting Apache 2'
oe sudo systemctl restart apache2
oe sudo systemctl status apache2

ol "Installing MySQL"
oe sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
oe sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
oe sudo apt-get -q -y install mysql-server mysql-client
oe sudo systemctl restart mysql
oe sudo systemctl status mysql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can play with `sed` command to make a replacement in file, something like

```
sed -i "s/DocumentRoot.*/DocumentRoot <your new path>" <path to httpd/apache2.conf>
```

PS:

- -i makes a backup of your file
- DocumentRoot.* will replace all line starting with DocumentRoot (dont remember by heart if there are multiple lines starting with DocumentRoot; in this case, make the correct pattern and not wildcard)
- if you have `/` in your new path, make sure to use `\/`

The other option (probably a bit more simple) is to push a new conf file under the `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/` directory with your specific setting, in case you have other settings such as `VirtualHost` or other it will make it more simple

Comment: Thanks this helped

Comment: sed -i "/DocumentRoot.*/DocumentRoot /var/www/" </etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf> sorry im a beginner but this is what i made out of it.

Comment: oh my bad I forgot an important piece in sed 1st argument must **s** `sed -i "s/DocumentRoot.*/RootDocument \/var\/www/" /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

Comment: After adding this line    ol 'changing root directory'
`sed -i "s/DocumentRoot.*/RootDocument \/var\/www/" /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`
ol 'done'  it still sees the html folder as the root, I want it to use the www folder instead

Comment: hum ... is it still `/var/www/html` in the conf file ? can you run the sed command from CLI directly and make sure it makes the change

Comment: `ol 'changing root directory'
sed -i "s/DocumentRoot.*/RootDocument \/var\/www/" /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
ol 'done'`

`ol 'Restarting Apache 2'
oe sudo systemctl restart apache2
oe sudo systemctl status apache2`

Comment: right, you already had this `Restarting Apache 2` part in your script (before mysql install)  so just make sure you run the  the sed command before that and you dont need to rerestart after

Comment: sorry about the DocumentRoot vs RootDocument, I see it was correct in the original answer but somehow I mess up in comments !